# How to update terminal title with the last command run in it?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal

*N.B. I haven't tagged this* [mintty](/questions/tagged/mintty) or [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) *to keep it universal, and because I've generally found that with stuff like this,* [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)/[linux](/questions/tagged/linux) *solutions tend to be interchangeable with Mintty/Cygwin ones, but I will change these if the answer turns out to be Mintyy/Cygwin-specific.*

---

I run Cygwin on top of Windows 10, and at any given time have several Mintty terminals open running different commands. It would be nice to be able to see at a glance which command was last run in each of these terminals instead of having to open each one to check.

The closest question I've found to my own is [this one for Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076127/bash-update-terminal-title-by-running-a-second-command/5076176#5076176), but the solutions to it, such as this:

```
trap 'echo -ne "\033]2;$(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g")\007"' DEBUG
```

...only add the command to the title for as long as the command is running - this isn't what I want because I need to be able to see the last command I ran in a terminal whether it's finished running or not.

Is this possible with `bash`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `PS1` probably resets the title. E.g. in my case it's

```
\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$
```

(with a trailing space), where `\e]0;\w\a` is responsible for the phenomenon. You want to get rid of this fragment (and `\[` `\]` around it):

```
PS1='\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '
```

Now it should work.

<sup>…unless the terminal emulator interferes. My Konsole in Kubuntu does interfere: it displays `bash` in the title after a command finishes, regardless if `PS1` resets the title. It's not important how it knows the right moment. I tested xterm, it doesn't interfere. And Mintty in Windows doesn't interfere, so a modified `PS1` is probably the only thing you need.</sup>

Consider changing the title via `PS1` anyway to indicate that the command has finished:

```bsh
# quick and dirty example
trap '
   _LASTCOM="$(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g")"
   printf "\e]0;%s\a" "$_LASTCOM"
   ' DEBUG
PS1='\[\e]0;*$_LASTCOM\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '
```

In the trap I store the relevant string in a variable, so it can be reused in `PS1` without running `sed` for the second time. I changed your `echo -e` to `printf`, so backslash-escaped characters (if any) coming from the expansion of `$_LASTCOM` are not interpreted.

Comment: Perfect answer as usual. It was indeed the PS1 that was resetting the solution from the other question, and I used your last solution to update the PS1 with a completed state, although I replaced the `*` with a `: done` to make it more clear: `PS1='\[\e]0;$_LASTCOM: done\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '`.

Comment: Nvm, I now see the logic of you putting it at the beginning and making it short. I'll do some experimenting to see what looks good, but might end up just changing it back to the asterisk.

Answer (score 4):

`PS1` changes the prompt once the command returns. `PS0` is more adequate in this case as it changes the prompt before the execution of the command.

First thing is to get rid of the bit in `PS1` that sets the window title, which looks like `\[\e]0;<some string>\a\]`. Otherwise every time a command returns `PS1` will overwrite the window title.

I found it easier to use a bash function to set `PS0`:

```
function current_command {
    local history_line="$(history 1)"
    echo "${history_line##*([[:space:])+([[:digit:]])+([[:space:]])}"
}

PS0='\[\e]0;$(current_command)\a\]'
PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

It has been tested on a debian/xterm.